# Foreach array to update table of database use those element of array

Tags: php, arrays

How to get the first value of element of array in php.
My story board is like this:

I have an array like this:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 68
        [MATERIAL] => I have
        [AC] => Try
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 69
        [MATERIAL] => It 
        [AC] => No Surrender
    )
```

)

I want to update some record on my database like this,

> foreach element of array,
>
> UPDATE MY TABEL SET MATERIAL = [MATERIAL], AC = [AC] where id= [id]

this is the model named m_admin :

```
public function update_eir_to_cost($id, $material, $ac) {
    $data = array(
        "MATERIAL" => $material,
        "AC" => $ac);
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->where($id);
    $this->db->update('tb_repair_detail', $data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        // generate an error... or use the log_message() function to log your error
        echo "Error Updating";
    } else {
        echo "Alhamdulillah";
    }
}
```

This is the controller :

```
public function update_json_detail() {
    $post_data = $this->input->post("POST_ARRAY");
    $execute = array();
    foreach ($post_data as $data) {
        $execute[] = array(
            'ID'=> $data['0'],
            'MATERIAL' => $data['7'],
            'AC' => $data['8']
        );
    }


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($execute); // return an array like above.

    /*forech element
        update table using model
    */

}
```

Comment: what framework are you using? Codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
public function update_json_detail() {
    $post_data = $this->input->post("POST_ARRAY");
    $execute = array();
    foreach ($post_data as $data) {
        $execute[] = array(
            'ID'=> $data['0'],
            'MATERIAL' => $data['7'],
            'AC' => $data['8']
        );
    }


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($execute); // return an array like above.

    $this->load->model('m_admin');

    foreach ($execute as $row) {
        $this->m_admin->update_eir_to_cost($row['ID'], $row['MATERIAL'], $row['AC']);
    }
}
```